# Creating HSQLDB Procedure in DbVisualizer

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, hsqldb, dbvisualizer

I am trying to create the following simple `HSQLDB` procedure, by a DbVisualizer client.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_procedure;
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure(OUT my_output INTEGER, IN my_input INTEGER)
        MODIFIES SQL DATA -- NO SQL
        BEGIN ATOMIC
                SET my_output = my_input;
        END
```

Error message:

```
[CREATE - 0 rows, 0.001 secs]  [Code: -5590, SQL State: 42590]  unexpected end of statement:  required: ; : line: 3
[END - 0 rows, 0.000 secs]  [Code: -5581, SQL State: 42581]  unexpected token: END
... 2 statement(s) executed, 0 rows affected, exec/fetch time: 0.001/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 2 errors]
```

It looks like [there is a problem](https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/discussion/73674/thread/58937080/) with the interpretation of `;`, but I could not find anything in `HSQLDB` equivalent to `MySQl` `delimiter`.

**How do I get around this problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DbVisualizer, I can use the DbVisualizer-specific delimiter.

```
@delimiter ++;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_procedure;
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure(OUT my_output INTEGER, IN my_input INTEGER)
        MODIFIES SQL DATA -- NO SQL
        BEGIN ATOMIC
                SET my_output = my_input;
        END
;
++
@delimiter ;++
```

From the [Dbvisualizer documentation](http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG100/Executing+Complex+Statements#ExecutingComplexStatements-Usingthe@delimitercommand):

> **Using the @delimiter command**
>
> With the @delimiter command you can temporarily change the statement
>   delimiter DbVisualizer uses to separate the statements and send them
>   one by one to the database. Use it before the complex statement, and
>   after the statement if the script contains additional statements.
>   Here's an example:
>
> ```
> @delimiter ++;
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION HELLO (p1 IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
> AS
> BEGIN
>  RETURN 'Hello ' || p1;
> END;
> ++
> @delimiter ;++
> @call ${returnValue||(null)||String||noshow dir=out}$ = HELLO('World');
> @echo returnValue = ${returnValue}$;
> ```
>
> The first @delimiter command sets the delimiter to ++ so that the
>   default ; delimiter can be used within the function body in the CREATE
>   statement. The ++ delimiter is then used to end the CREATE statement,
>   and another @delimiter command sets the delimiter back to ; for the
>   remaining commands in the script.